# send $_POST to .php file without using CURL

Tags: php, post, curl

Im looking for an alternative to send $_POST data to a .php file without using CURL as it increases loading time of my index.php. Are there any?

I have a file that receives $_POST data and loads file depending on the data received. I've tried using CURL but it greatly increases the loading time of the document. are there any faster alternatives to make 2 php files to communicate with each other without revealing the data sent?

Comment: the bottleneck is almost certainly in the network, not the PHP function that you use. So replacing `curl` with something else won't make a difference.

Comment: yeah, I doubt `curl` is your bottleneck. All it does is send out a network request. You could try `wget` if you want an alternative.

Comment: currently in developing in XAMPP, which leave's me even more clueless as the file is located in same folder as my index.php. Is there any way to debug the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for  `wget` program..It retrieves content from web servers.

Here is the download [link](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/)